# request returns response 412

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

I'm trying to access a Chinese website(http://www.nhc.gov.cn/wjw/gfxwjj/list.shtml) with python, but it returns the request status code [412]

```
HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
            'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'ja, en-US;q=0.9, en;q=0.8'})
 
url = 'http://www.nhc.gov.cn/wjw/gfxwjj/list.shtml'
res = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
print(res)
```

Does anyone know how to fix it?
I can access the website with normal browsers.
And I can also get a status code[200] when I access the other website with python.
Thanks.

Comment: Try to look like a browser: make sure that all request headers and their order are the same as your browser. If that doesn't help, use a headless browser like selenium or splash screen to render the js.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I made the all request headers exactly same as my browser. But things didn't change. I also tried selenium, but it showed only white screen.

Comment: The HTTP Status Code 412 means that the server does not meet one of the preconditions that the client put in its request header fields.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'm glad if you know what exactly I should do for fixing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I could solved this problem by myself.
The problem was caused because of the Navigator.webdriver was "TRUE".
Some websites block the access from the webdriver.

To solve this, I use selenium with chromedriver and set the Navigator.webdriver "undefined".
The exact code to do this is below,

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='your chromedriver's path', chrome_options=options)
```

Thank you for everyone who tried to solve my problem.
I hope it'll help someone who has the same problem.